# HTTP monitoring for PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, http, http-headers, monitor

Is there any tools like httpwatch/fiddler available to monitor the headers send by PHP API like file_get_contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get them yourself: just query by `file_get_contents()` your own script with (supposing you're using apache):

```
print_r(apache_request_headers());
```

And there you'll get all the headers being sent by `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 3):

Functions like `file_get_contents` only send minimal headers (HTTP method and `host`) as it's up to the developer to add any additional headers. You can see this for yourself by making a request to a script on your own server.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit too much for your needs, but you can sniff any network packets with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)